# Why not allow code formatting selection like synonyms?

Tags: feature-request, tags, code-formatting

Instead of having to ask on Meta every time a new tag needs to be associated with a particular code-formatting hint, could this be decided automatically by the users of the tag?

I see this working very similar to how tag synonyms are voted on.  You'd have to have a particular rating in that tag to suggest or vote.  If there were conflicting suggestions, then the one with the most votes would win, unless overridden by a moderator.

For example, this would prevent from having to ask that every JavaScript library out there be formatted as JavaScript when the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag is not provided.

Comment: (Really, though, the JavaScript tag ought to be provided.)